# DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator() is returning output as ','44 instead of ','

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I am trying to set the keylistener for editext in android. Since for europe countries we should have "," as a decimal seperator I am using DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator() this method to get the seperator based on locale. But, when I tried for french it is returning ','44 instead of ',' how can I fix the same. Only for europe countries I need "," instead of "." as a decimal seperator. Below is the code which I tried to get the decimal seperator and set the same to editext keylistener.

```
char separator = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();
mWeightEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789" + separator));
```

Comment: Where do you get this `','44`? It doesn't make sense. `separator` is a `char`, not a string.

Comment: Since 44 is the ASCII value for the comma, are you sure you're not printing it somewhere both as a `char` and as an integer?

Comment: Hi @Federico DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator(); this method is returning me the char value like this ','44.

Comment: Let me clarify my question: how do you know that? I mean, how are you checking the return value?

Comment: As I pasted the code in my question I am initializing the string variable like below
char separator = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();

so, when I am debugging I got to know that it is returning ','44.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this in the debugger

[image]

(here I had a `char c = ',';`)

It is just the way the debugger shows the variable's value. The variable's value is really `','`, that is ASCII 44.

Comment: But when I am appending char value to the string like mWeightEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789" + separator));
in my android softkeyboard instead of "," it is showing ".-".

Comment: That's a different problem. You should open another question about that, along the lines of "Why does `DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,")` show a `'.'` instead of a `','`?" As an aside, what happens when you try `DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,")` directly?

Comment: when I tried this  DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,") also same issues. Thats why I attached both java and android tags while asking this question. Should I ask one more question with android tag alone now?

Comment: In my opinion yes, because your original question was about the weird '44' after the comma. But keep the java tag as well.